# How to generate xades signed properties hash of e invoice?

Tags: php, xml, digital-signature, xades

I have tried many times and many ways to get the xadesSignedProperties encoded hash (DigestValue) but always I get uncorrect result .
I have this singed properties :

```html
                                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2023-07-17T18:22:23Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                                    <ds:DigestValue>ZDE1MzZmNzFhOGNjZTc2ZjIzMWEwZTg4ZWY0MzlkNGQwMThkOWQ2MjQ2ZTdkNWM5YTczMjlhNzA4MjJlMWVhMw==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>O=Alamal For Gold and Jewellery, OU=HEAD-OFFICE, C=SA, CN=ALAMAL</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>408202254781608792003747220510677813404473504788</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
```

I followed the steps in the documentation :

[image]

But I always get the wrong digest value .
The digest value of the previous signed propeties should be

```
MzBkOWYwMDc0ZGNhMWE2YzA0NDVlZWJmYTc5NmUwYTM1M2Q5NjhiMjMwNDc2YmJjNGJhYWM2ZDQ3NjYwNzU3YQ==
```

as it is shown in this xadesSignedProperties block :

```html
<ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                <ds:DigestValue>MzBkOWYwMDc0ZGNhMWE2YzA0NDVlZWJmYTc5NmUwYTM1M2Q5NjhiMjMwNDc2YmJjNGJhYWM2ZDQ3NjYwNzU3YQ==</ds:DigestValue>
     </ds:Reference>
```

I Looked to these answers but also I couldn't get the correct digest value .

[How to compute the digest for the SignedProperties of a XAdES signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757454/how-to-compute-the-digest-for-the-signedproperties-of-a-xades-signature)

[how can i hash a specific tag from XML file in a correct way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250578/how-can-i-hash-a-specific-tag-from-xml-file-in-a-correct-way/75433385#75433385)

This is one of my tries :

```
    $populateSignedPropertiesOutputXML = new DOMDocument(encoding: 'utf-8');
    $populateSignedPropertiesOutputXML->loadXML(str_replace("\r", "", $signedPropertiesBlock));

    $populatedSignedPropertiesString = $populateSignedPropertiesOutputXML->C14N();

    $populatedSignedPropertiesString = unpack('H*', $populatedSignedPropertiesString)['1'];

    $hashedSignedProperties = hash('sha256', $populatedSignedPropertiesString);

    return base64_encode($hashedSignedProperties);
```